# Is OpenFlow driver with v1.5 protocol support currently in place

Tags: openflow

I'm looking for OpenFlow v1.5 driver implementation(open source) and what I've found is as followings.

1. libfluid - http://opensourcesdn.org/projects/openflow-driver-project/
2. CPqD/ofsoftswitch13 - https://github.com/CPqD/ofsoftswitch13

And basically they are based on the same source, Cpqd's 1.3 driver.

I'm wondering if the open source implementation of OpenFlow 1.5 is currently in place or not.

Please notice that I'm not looking for controller supporting OpenFlow v1.5 protocol. The implementation of v1.5 protocol providing the basic features to implement an OpenFlow controller is what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try loxigen.

https://github.com/floodlight/loxigen

It is a library with language bindings for OpenFlow that supports versions 
1.0, 1.1, 1.2, and 1.3.1, 1.4.1, and 1.5.1.

Notice that the documentation says version 1.5.1 is still experimental and has support only to Java.